# CSS Pseudo Element Counters: can you increment an alphabet letter "a", "b", "c", etc instead of a number?

Tags: css, pseudo-element, css-content

As defined here:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#propdef-counter-increment

You can use code like the following to increment numbers in pseudo elements.

```css
H1:before {
    content: "Chapter " counter(chapter) ". ";
    counter-increment: chapter;  /* Add 1 to chapter */
}
H1 {
    counter-reset: section;      /* Set section to 0 */
}
H2:before {
    content: counter(chapter) "." counter(section) " ";
    counter-increment: section;
}
```

Is there a way you can use the same code to increment letters like "a", "b", "c", etc?

Thank you!

Comment: This didn't work for me as-is, I had to move the "counter-increment" declaration from `h1:before` to `h1`

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Yes, the second argument to `counter()` defines the type of counter used, as for the `list-style-type` from a regular `ul` or `ol`; for example:

```
content: counter(chapter, lower-alpha);
```

```css
ul {
  counter-reset: listStyle;
}
ul li {
  margin-left: 1em;
  counter-increment: listStyle;
}
ul li::before {
  margin-right: 1em;
  content: counter(listStyle, lower-alpha);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/H4vwU/1/).

Others include: `decimal`, `decimal-leading-zero`, `lower-roman`, `upper-roman`, `lower-greek`, `lower-latin`, `upper-latin`, `armenian`, `georgian`, `lower-alpha`, `upper-alpha`.

As there seems to have been something of an update to the above list of styles, I chose to add a code snippet which allows the user to choose from the (currently-) available options, along with an 'output' area, to show how to use that style with CSS generated-content:

```js
let select = document.querySelector('select'),
  output = document.querySelector('#currentCounter'),
  changeEvent = new Event('change');

select.addEventListener('change', function() {
  document.body.style.setProperty('--listStyleType', this.value);
  output.textContent = this.value;
});

select.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
```

```css
body {
  --listStyleType: decimal;
}

ul {
  counter-reset: listStyle;
  columns: 2;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
  counter-increment: listStyle;
}

ul li::before {
  content: counter(listStyle, var(--listStyleType));
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  line-height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

code {
  display: block;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  width: 80%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 1em auto;
  padding: 0.5em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px limegreen;
}

code::after {
  content: '\A';
}

#currentCounter {
  color: #f90;
}
```

```html
<label for="counterChoice">Please select a CSS counter:</label>
<select id="counterChoice">
  <option value="arabic-indic">arabic-indic</option>
  <option value="armenian">armenian</option>
  <option value="bengali">bengali</option>
  <option value="cambodian">cambodian</option>
  <option value="circle">circle</option>
  <option value="cjk-decimal">cjk-decimal</option>
  <option value="cjk-earthly-branch">cjk-earthly-branch</option>
  <option value="cjk-heavenly-stem">cjk-heavenly-stem</option>
  <option value="decimal">decimal</option>
  <option value="decimal-leading-zero">decimal-leading-zero</option>
  <option value="devanagari">devanagari</option>
  <option value="disc">disc</option>
  <option value="disclosure-closed">disclosure-closed</option>
  <option value="disclosure-open">disclosure-open</option>
  <option value="ethiopic-numeric">ethiopic-numeric</option>
  <option value="georgian">georgian</option>
  <option value="gujarati">gujarati</option>
  <option value="gurmukhi">gurmukhi</option>
  <option value="hebrew">hebrew</option>
  <option value="hiragana">hiragana</option>
  <option value="hiragana-iroha">hiragana-iroha</option>
  <option value="japanese-formal">japanese-formal</option>
  <option value="japanese-informal">japanese-informal</option>
  <option value="kannada">kannada</option>
  <option value="katakana">katakana</option>
  <option value="katakana-iroha">katakana-iroha</option>
  <option value="khmer">khmer</option>
  <option value="korean-hangul-formal">korean-hangul-formal</option>
  <option value="korean-hanja-formal">korean-hanja-formal</option>
  <option value="korean-hanja-informal">korean-hanja-informal</option>
  <option value="lao">lao</option>
  <option value="lower-alpha">lower-alpha</option>
  <option value="lower-alpha">lower-alpha</option>
  <option value="lower-armenian">lower-armenian</option>
  <option value="lower-greek">lower-greek</option>
  <option value="lower-latin">lower-latin</option>
  <option value="lower-roman">lower-roman</option>
  <option value="malayalam">malayalam</option>
  <option value="mongolian">mongolian</option>
  <option value="myanmar">myanmar</option>
  <option value="oriya">oriya</option>
  <option value="persian">persian</option>
  <option value="simp-chinese-formal">simp-chinese-formal</option>
  <option value="simp-chinese-informal">simp-chinese-informal</option>
  <option value="square">square</option>
  <option value="tamil">tamil</option>
  <option value="telugu">telugu</option>
  <option value="thai">thai</option>
  <option value="tibetan">tibetan</option>
  <option value="trad-chinese-formal">trad-chinese-formal</option>
  <option value="trad-chinese-informal">trad-chinese-informal</option>
  <option value="upper-alpha">upper-alpha</option>
  <option value="upper-armenian">upper-armenian</option>
  <option value="upper-latin">upper-latin</option>
  <option value="upper-roman">upper-roman</option>
</select>
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
  <li>five</li>
  <li>six</li>
  <li>seven</li>
  <li>eight</li>
  <li>nine</li>
  <li>ten</li>
</ul>

<code>
  li::before {
    content: counter(&lt;counterName&gt;, <span id="currentCounter"></span>)
  }
</code>
```

The currently-available (as of 2017-02-27):

- arabic-indic
- armenian
- bengali
- cambodian
- circle
- cjk-decimal
- cjk-earthly-branch
- cjk-heavenly-stem
- decimal
- decimal-leading-zero
- devanagari
- disc
- disclosure-closed
- disclosure-open
- ethiopic-numeric
- georgian
- gujarati
- gurmukhi
- hebrew
- hiragana
- hiragana-iroha
- japanese-formal
- japanese-informal
- kannada
- katakana
- katakana-iroha
- khmer
- korean-hangul-formal
- korean-hanja-formal
- korean-hanja-informal
- lao
- lower-alpha
- lower-alpha
- lower-armenian
- lower-greek
- lower-latin
- lower-roman
- malayalam
- mongolian
- myanmar
- oriya
- persian
- simp-chinese-formal
- simp-chinese-informal
- square
- tamil
- telugu
- thai
- tibetan
- trad-chinese-formal
- trad-chinese-informal
- upper-alpha
- upper-armenian
- upper-latin
- upper-roman

References:

- [`list-style-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type).
- "[Generated Content, automatic numbering and lists](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#counter-styles)," from the W3 (now outdated).
- "[CSS Counter Styles, Level 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-counter-styles-3/)," from the W3.

Comment: And of course, a link to the part of the spec itself that mentions this: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#counter-styles (since the OP linked to the spec)

Comment: Terrific reply. Thank you :)