# How to remove dot '.' from CSS list-style:decimal

Tags: php, html, css, list, html-lists

Is there any way to remove the DOT after the decimal numbers in List style?

My CSS

```
.snum li {list-style:decimal outside none;}
```

The result i was getting like this (not including PHP and HTML code)

```
1. MILK
2. SOYA
3. BEANS
4. GARLIC
```

Desired Outpiut should be like this.

```
1 MILK
2 SOYA
3 BEANS
4 GARLIC
```

Comment: You could try using a counter http://stackoverflow.com/a/5742176/1353011

Comment: It looks better with the decimal anyways. Sometimes the answer you didn't want to hear is the correct one. If you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945161/html-css-ordered-list-without-the-period and that was not your solution and you must remove the period, maybe you don't want to use lists at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by implementing a custom counter as a pseudo-element before each `<li>` on your ordered list:

#### HTML:

```
<ol>
    <li>STUFF</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
</ol>
```

#### CSS:

```
ol
{
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 0;
}

li
{
    counter-increment: custom;
}

ol li:before
{
    content: counter(custom) " ";   
}

ol li:first-child {
    counter-reset: custom;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/18zteb4n/2)

Comment: What about with `lower-alpha` and such? Also TIL about the `counter()` function

Comment: Found the answer: `content: counter(chapter, lower-alpha);` (credit to David SRM https://stackoverflow.com/a/16943843/1025702)