# How do I make <li> tags in a <ol> use letters

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want my WP site to have a ordered list instead of listing with numbers it will list with letters.

I have applied attributes to the OL and it doesn't work.  It is most likeley just a syntax error.  I copied and pasted from some forum but it didn't work on my WP site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Pseudo Element Counters: can you increment an alphabet letter "a", "b", "c", etc instead of a number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943805/css-pseudo-element-counters-can-you-increment-an-alphabet-letter-a-b-c)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `list-style-type` CSS property on the `<ol>` tag.

Eg.

```
ol {
    list-style-type: lower-alpha;
}
```

See here for the full list of options: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-type.asp

Comment: Here is a more reliable source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type

Comment: Boo w3schools references

Comment: @WillReese, yes yes, but in this case there's not much that can go wrong just listing the options.

Comment: I tried both of these ways and neither of them worked.  I had the css in the <style> tags and I had the html but it still didn't work.  It displayed the list but it was still using the numbers.  Any suggestions.  Thanks.  @WillReese

Comment: @AidanD there is a strong chance you are running into CSS Specificity issues. Use a tool like Chrome Developer tools (Press f12) or FireBug for Firefox to inspect the list and see what styles are being applied from where.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the type attribute like this.

```
<ol type="a">
    <li>Apples</li>
    <li>Bananas</li>
    <li>Oranges</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: documentation for the type attribute can be found here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_ol_type.asp

Comment: Be careful using `type` it was deprecated but is back in [HTML 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ol.html#ol.attrs.type) with an altered meaning.If you are purely wanting to style the list a CSS alternative is better.

Comment: This is what I love about this site, even though I knew a solution, I just learned a better way.  =)

Comment: Try using the CSS solution mentioned in the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

If you use tailwindcss

```
<ul class="list-[lower-alpha]">
    <!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).