# How to number divs like a list but to duplicate each number and add an A and B to the end

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to number a list in order depending on how many divs I have.

At the moment I am using some code to find the index of each of my divs, 1, 2, 3, etc., but what I really need is to have each div show 1A, 1B, 2A, and 2B, so that the number is duplicated and after the last number with the letter B, it moves on to the next number.

Here is the code I am using for the example:

HTML:

```
<div class="patch-cell">
    <div class="fader-number">test</div>
</div>
<div class="patch-cell">
    <div class="fader-number">test</div>
</div>
<div class="patch-cell">
    <div class="fader-number">test</div>
</div>
<div class="patch-cell">
    <div class="fader-number">test</div>
</div>
<div class="patch-cell">
    <div class="fader-number">test</div>
</div>

<!--example of how I want it to look--->

<div class="patch-cell-test">
    <div class="fader-number">Example  1 A</div>
</div>
<div class="patch-cell-test">
    <div class="fader-number">Example  1 B</div>
</div>
<div class="patch-cell-test">
    <div class="fader-number">Example  2 A</div>
</div>
<div class="patch-cell-test">
    <div class="fader-number">Example  2 B</div>
</div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
$('.patch-cell').each(function() {
    $(this).find('.fader-number').append('<span class="patching-numbering">' + ($(this).index() +1) + "</span>");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/susannalarsen/xj8d14yb/1/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to halve the index to get the number, and use the remainder to get the letter.

https://jsfiddle.net/xj8d14yb/3/

```
$('.patch-cell').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    // 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5...
    var number = $this.index() / 2 + 1;
    // A, B, A, B, A, B...
    var letter = $this.index() % 2 === 0 ? 'A' : 'B';
    $this.find('.fader-number').append(
        '<span class="patching-numbering">'
        // 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3...
        + Math.floor(number) 
        + letter 
        + "</span>");
});
```

Update: There's another way of doing this, where you get both the division and remainder at the same time.  You can do this by converting to a string and splitting on the decimal point.

https://jsfiddle.net/xj8d14yb/6/

```
$('.patch-cell').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var number = ($this.index() / 2 + 1).toString().split('.');
    $this.find('.fader-number').append(
        '<span class="patching-numbering">'
        + number[0] 
        + (number[1] !== '5' ? 'A' : 'B')
        + '</span>');
});
```

Answer (score 20):

There's no need to use JavaScript for this; You could simply use [CSS counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters).

```css
body {
  counter-reset: n;
}
.patch-cell:nth-child(odd) .fader-number:after {
  counter-increment: n;
  content: counter(n) "A";
}
.patch-cell:nth-child(even) .fader-number:after {
  content: counter(n) "B";
}
```

```html
<div class="patch-cell">
  <div class="fader-number">test</div>
</div>
<div class="patch-cell">
  <div class="fader-number">test</div>
</div>
<div class="patch-cell">
  <div class="fader-number">test</div>
</div>
<div class="patch-cell">
  <div class="fader-number">test</div>
</div>
<div class="patch-cell">
  <div class="fader-number">test</div>
</div>
```

If you really wanted to, you could counter the letters as well.

```css
body {
  counter-reset: main sub;
}
.patch-cell:nth-child(odd) {
  counter-reset: sub;
  counter-increment: main sub;
}
.patch-cell:nth-child(even) {
  counter-increment: sub;
}
.patch-cell .fader-number:after {
  content: counter(main) counter(sub, upper-alpha);
}
```

```html
<div class="patch-cell">
  <div class="fader-number">test</div>
</div>
<div class="patch-cell">
  <div class="fader-number">test</div>
</div>
<div class="patch-cell">
  <div class="fader-number">test</div>
</div>
<div class="patch-cell">
  <div class="fader-number">test</div>
</div>
<div class="patch-cell">
  <div class="fader-number">test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is brilliant!  Only limitation is that after tags don't support html, so it might not be appropriate depending on how complex the content was.

Comment: Really like the approach, and don't find it limiting unless you have to support crappy browsers.

Comment: great. @Nit. is it possible to put all letters through `counter(letter)`: 1A ,1B, 1C, ..., 2A, 2B, ... . Thanks you in advance

Comment: This was a great answer also and it was hard to choose between but only because I needed to choose between using css or jquery for this.  I wasn't aware I could do that in css so it has helped me alot. Thanks

Comment: @SheraliTurdiyev that is also a good question as I would be interested to know if it could cover that

Comment: @SheraliTurdiyev Yes it is, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943805/css-pseudo-element-counters-can-you-increment-an-alphabet-letter-a-b-c . I've also added an example to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

The best place to create such markup would be at the server with something like [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) or whatever server-side scripting language you may have access to.

In JavaScript, here is how to do it:

```
$('.patch-cell .fader-number').html(function(i,html) {
    return html + ' <span class="patching-numbering">' +
                  (Math.floor(i/2) + 1) +
                  ( i%2 ? ' B' : ' A' ) + '</span>';
});
```

```js
$('.patch-cell .fader-number').html(function(i,html) {
    return html + ' <span class="patching-numbering">' + (Math.floor(i/2) + 1) + ( i%2 ? ' B' : ' A' ) + '</span>';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="patch-cell">
    <div class="fader-number">test</div>
</div>
<div class="patch-cell">
    <div class="fader-number">test</div>
</div>
<div class="patch-cell">
    <div class="fader-number">test</div>
</div>
<div class="patch-cell">
    <div class="fader-number">test</div>
</div>
<div class="patch-cell">
    <div class="fader-number">test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Or do it like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xj8d14yb/5/):

```
$('.patch-cell .fader-number').each(function(i) {
 $(this).append('<span class="patching-numbering">'+(1+Math.floor(i/2)) +['A','B'][i%2]+"</span>");
});
```

Comment: the first time that i see this : ['A','B'][i%2],   it's great idea :)

Answer (score 1):

@JamesBrierley beat me to it, but here's an inline form.

http://jsfiddle.net/xj8d14yb/4/

```
$('.patch-cell').each(function(i) {
    $(this).find('.fader-number').append('<span class="patching-numbering">' + Math.floor(i / 2 + 1) + (i % 2 ? 'B' : 'A') + "</span>");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.patch-cell').each(function() {
    $(this).find('.fader-number').append('<span class="patching-numbering">' + ($(this).index() +1) + ($(this).index()%2?' B':' A') + "</span>");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/x7q2uzh9/1/

Answer (score 1):

If you want a dynamic way, use **[this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sherali/qvtqwjkb/)**.

```
//You can put other letters (A,B,C,D,...) or another objects.
var array = ["A", "B", "C"];
$('.patch-cell').each(function (i) {
    var index = Math.ceil(($(this).index() + 1) / array.length), 
        r = index + " " + array[i % array.length];

    $(this)
        .find('.fader-number')
        .append('<span class="patching-numbering">' +r + "</span>");
});
```