# Shared variables between JS and SCSS in Vue

Tags: javascript, sass, vue.js, vuejs2

I've recently started using Vue.js 2, and I'm a fan of the single-file component structure:

```
<template>
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  name: 'hello-world',
};
</script>


<style scoped lang="scss">
h1 {
  font-size: 72px;
}
</style>
```

I'm curious if there's an established way to pass variables between SCSS and JS, though. I need to share a value, and right now it's duplicated in both sections.

I used the Vue CLI to create this project, so it's being bundled with Webpack 2, using the vue-loader. I'm hoping there's a way to configure it to populate variables from JS to SCSS, or vice-versa.

Comment: I can't offer specific insight into [tag:scss], but [tag:css-variables] have JavaScript setters and getters; use of which is shown in the following answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36088890/82548 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/16943843/82548 (disclaimer: the second answer is one of my own).

Comment: Thanks David! Yeah, I'm hoping that there's a way with vue-loader, to handle it during the bundle process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question would benefit from more details. How thorough of an integration do you need? There's this which would allow you to create a JSON file and get those values as SCSS variables as well as JS (obviously).

https://github.com/Updater/node-sass-json-importer

If you want something more simple you can also create inline styles by using `:style`. That way it would be dynamic.

So something like:

```
<div :style="{ height: heightInPixels }">...</div>
```

Here's a quick demo of it: https://jsfiddle.net/4s25kca2/

It really depends on your exact need.

Comment: Hey Bill, thanks for your time. So yeah, I'm familiar with the techniques you mention, I was just hoping there was a method in Vue-loader (or an associated plugin) I was missing. Specifically, I'm setting an element's opacity dynamically based on scroll position (to fade it in). I wound up reading this value straight from the DOM via getBoundingClientRect; it's not as elegant a solution, but it works just fine.