# CSS Counters: Can you increment by non-integers (i.e. floats)?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I've seen that you can use various types of counters, as described in the accepted answer to this question: [CSS Pseudo Element Counters: can you increment an alphabet letter "a", "b", "c", etc instead of a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943805/css-pseudo-element-counters-can-you-increment-an-alphabet-letter-a-b-c)

However, is it possible to increment by a float, e.g. 0.5? This would give a list of, say, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, etc.

Here is what I've tried to do, to no avail:

```
.values li:before {
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step 0.5;
}
```

The value after `step` is not recognized if it's a float (only if integer).

If this is not possible, is there another method I could use to programmatically set the `<li>` elements as desired?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fake it with multiple rules and `nth-child` etc

```css
ul {
  counter-reset: numbers;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li:before {
  padding-right: 1em;
}

li:nth-of-type(2n+1)::before {
  counter-increment: numbers;
}

li:nth-child(odd)::before {
  content: counters(numbers, "") ".0";
}

li:nth-child(even)::before {
  content: counters(numbers, "") ".5";
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem</li>
  <li>Lorem</li>
  <li>Lorem</li>
  <li>Lorem</li>
  <li>Lorem</li>
  <li>Lorem</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Great solution. I'm accepting this one because it uses pure CSS, as the question requested.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without any hacks, CSS supports this feature. You need to add few `counters` to content value.

```css
ol {
    counter-reset: section;
    list-style-type: none;
    counter-reset: subsection;
    counter-increment: section;
}

li::before {
    counter-increment: subsection 5;
    content: counter(section) "." counter(subsection) " ";
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item     
    <ol>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Interesting approach, although what you wrote doesn't exactly work in that it's not adding 0.5 each time, but rather adding 5 after the decimal. So when the second counter it gets to 10, it should increase the first counter and revert to 0. It should go 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, etc. Not 1, 1.5, 1.10, 1.15, 1.20, 1.25...that's not how decimals work.

Comment: I doubt it could be done by pure CSS for you requirements, but if you using SASS or another preprocessor, may be it could be done by @if statements. If you ask, I will search for answer. But in this case, the top answer much more easier i guess.

Comment: Yeah I think the accepted answers is a good workaround. No need to reinvent the wheel! I actually am using SCSS, but again the top answer works well enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

CSS probably isn't the best thing you can use for this. Try using JavaScript:

```js
var children = document.getElementById("values").children;
var value = 1;
for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
  var child = children[i];
  child.innerHTML = value + " " + child.innerHTML;
  value += 0.5;
}
```

```html
<ul id="values">
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is a good way to do it. For reference, the way I ended up doing this (I'm using React) is this: 
       
 ```
{values.map(value => {
          return (
            <li>{value}</li>
          )
        })}
```
Where `values` is an array containing the steps (created with a for loop starting at the min value and ending at the max value, adding the step value each time).