# How to customise section headings to start with letters in r markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

While we can automate number section by adding the option `number_sections: true` to in the YAML header, I wonder if we can change the headings style in `r markdown`. For example, can we customise it with letters like following?

> **A. Section A**
>
> > **A.1 Subsection**
> >
> > > **A.1.1 Sub subsection 1**
> > >
> > > **A.1.2 Sub subsection 1**
>
> **B. Section B**
>
> > **B.1 Subsection**
> >
> > > **B.1.1 Sub subsection**

Comment: what is the output format?

Comment: @romles, html or pdf will do. For pdf, I have tried by creating a header.tex with customised styles and include it in YAML, but no avail (probably due to my rusty LaTex skills). For html, I think a customised CSS might be feasible but I have no experience with html. Any tip?

Comment: I've an answer for html with css.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was downvoted.

Comment: @romles, maybe the title is not clear enough?

Comment: Sure, *headings* is more appropriate than *prefix*. I edited your Q & my A.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Answer for `pdf_document`

Save this line in an external file (e.g. `inheader.tex`):

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
```

and insert the file in document's header with:

```
---
title: "Lettered sections"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: true
    includes:
      in_header: inheader.tex
---
```

### Answer for `html_document` format

#### tl;dr

Knit this `Rmd` file:

````
---
title: "Lettered sections"
output: html_document
---

```{css, echo=FALSE}
.header-section-number {
  display: none;
}

body {
  counter-reset: counter-level-1;
}

h1:not(.title) {
  counter-increment: counter-level-1;
  counter-reset: counter-level-2;
}

h1:not(.title)::before{
  content: counter(counter-level-1, upper-alpha) ". ";
}

h2 {
  counter-increment: counter-level-2;
  counter-reset: counter-level-3;
}

h2::before {
  content: counter(counter-level-1, upper-alpha) "." counter(counter-level-2) " ";
}

h3 {
  counter-increment: counter-level-3;
}

h3::before {
  content: counter(counter-level-1, upper-alpha) "." counter(counter-level-2) "." counter(counter-level-3) " ";
}
```

# Section

## Subsection

### Sub subsection

### Sub subsection

## Subsection

# Section

## Subsection

### Sub subsection

## Subsection
````

**Explanations**
*Number sections* is a native `pandoc`'s option. It seems that `pandoc` does not provide any support for hierarchical headings customisation.

So, there are three options with HTML output:

- deeply dive into `pandoc` and develop a new writer, because hierarchical headings are declared as integers [see here, line #105](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/8ffb4e5b334a302ba7b07c4213e7102c23ef7721/src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/HTML.hs). Note there's a [relevant recent issue](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/4258) in order to facilitate headings customisation.
- modify HTML rendering using CSS.
- modify HTML elements with Javascript. This may be necessary for `toc: true`.

This answer provides an example of hierarchical headings customisation with CSS. It is recommended to save all the CSS code (*i.e.* lines 7 to 39) to an external file with `.css` extension and include it in HTML report using this YAML header:

```
---
title: "Lettered sections"
output: 
  html_document:
    css: "filename.css"
---
```

**Additional note**
One can use other counters than numeric or alpha, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943805/css-pseudo-element-counters-can-you-increment-an-alphabet-letter-a-b-c) for a list.
You also can define your own set of counter with [`@counter-style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@counter-style).

Comment: these work! Thank for the elegant solutions, especially with LaTex command!

Comment: Do I understand correctly that `number_sections: true` with HTML output does not create CSS counters that we can work with? Thus, we have to turn that off and make our own counters, right?

Comment: @randy this is correct. `number_sections: true` produces only numeric hierarchical headings. We need to turn this option off to customize the headings.